# How to swap model as keyframe?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I want to make animation in Blender but in way what is closer to me as pixel artist. I want to make frame-by-frame animation with 3d models but to do so i need to set model itself as keyframe. I need to swap mesh,UVs and textures while keeping everything else. Also i need to say all frames have different count of vertices. It is even possible ? Is possible to set only mesh,uv and texture on same object while keeping everything else, 60 times pre secound ?
If someone knows how it can be done, please help me.

Comment: You can animate visibility. Also look into using `Shape Keys`

Comment: @VRM I cannot use Shape Keys because most of frames have different count of vertices.I know i can animate visibility but i want avoid it because i have 5 scenes, 50 models pre scene and 200-500 frames pre model, and only 4gb ram. My computer cannot take so much models.